# How to send ajax request to check session timeout and render relogin message in grails?

Tags: ajax, grails

I want to display a message to the user saying, *"you're logged out re-login please!"* when session is timed-out, sending an **ajax request** each time. If session timer ends i want to send final ajax request displaying above message. But the problem here is i don't know where should i have to keep my ajax and jquery codes and since i don't have much knowledge about ajax request, can anyone explain this process with codes. In siple my requirement is like of what facebook shows on session time out, or when any one tab in case of multiople tabs are logged out. I'm working on ***grails project***.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do your ajax request like this

```
$.ajax({
    url:url,
    type:"POST",  // or get
    data:parameters,
    success: function(data) {
    // do procedure if success
          }
    error : function(xhr, type, error){
    // do procedure if fail
            // may be send a message to the server side to display a message that     shows session timeout
       }
});
```

Handle your session timeout in the error function

Comment: thanks yarr it worked but still i have a problem like when i am opening multiple tabs and if i log out on any one i want to show this message automatically on other pages for which i thing i have to catch the last request. i think cookies concept is applied but i don't know can you help me out with this too??

Comment: so is the situation like this...Once the user logs out, every other tab should display a pop-up kindof thing showing that the session is expired ?

Comment: I think the way it happens in facebook is that it is sending ajax requests continuously at some interval from every page that is loaded. So these requests could be caught and processed if session expires in between.

Comment: yes as we see on the facebook tabs hope you have already visualized but i'm not being able to design such how could ido any idea?

Comment: yes in my case too i would be sending multiple ajax request which would be checked/processed every 5 second if session is not timed out its alright if not it will so a popup with message . by the ay can i get the idea of catching last ajax request ?

Comment: The approach i 've told is good in the case of facebook where they have to refresh the content in the loaded page continuously. Do it only if you have such a requirement. It could be done like this :  setInterval(function() {  your ajax requests  }, 5000);

Comment: Check the functions in this page  :  http://www.jquery4u.com/jquery-functions/setinterval-example/#.UA0ijTuzBoE   Set the timeouts like that.  (If you have trouble reading the unformatted comment)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14338/discussion-between-user1252814-and-sreejith)

Answer (score 0):

I did it myself and this is the js code for it "gracefulSession.js" and call this javascript at the page where you are going to embed your html code..

```
function checkSessionStatus() {

    var lStorage = getLocalStorage();
    if (lStorage) {
        //lStorage.setItem('poleTime',new Date());
        var poleTime = lStorage.getItem("poleTime");
        var parsedTime;
        try {
            parsedTime = new Date(poleTime);
        } catch (e) {}

        //alert(new Date()-parsedTime)
        //alert(new Date())
        //alert(parsedTime)

        //3900000 = 1H5M

        if (parsedTime && (new Date() - parsedTime) < 3900000) {
            //alert('NCATCH'+parsedTime);
        } else {
            //alert('POINT');
            poleSessionStatus();
        }
    }
}

function setlatestPoleTIme() {

    //alert("SETTING POLE TIME");
    var lStorage = getLocalStorage();
    if (lStorage) {
        lStorage.setItem('poleTime', new Date());
    }
}

function setCheckSessionTimer() {

    var lStorage = getLocalStorage();
    var isLoggedOut = false;
    if (lStorage) {
        if (lStorage.getItem('isLoggedOut') == 'true') {
            isLoggedOut = true;
        }
    }

    //console.log('checkingIfLoggedOut');

    if (!isLoggedOut) {

        setTimeout("setCheckSessionTimer();", 5000);
        //console.log("NOPT LO");
        $('#LoggedoutMessage').hide();
        checkSessionStatus();
    } else {

        setTimeout("setCheckSessionTimer();", 5000);
        //console.log("KO");
        //alert("You're Logged Out from  other tab");
        $('#LoggedoutMessage').show();

    }

}

function logout() {

    //alert("LOGGIN OUT")
    var lStorage = getLocalStorage();
    if (lStorage) {
        lStorage.setItem('isLoggedOut', 'true');
    }
}

function resetLoggedOutFLag() {

    var lStorage = getLocalStorage();
    if (lStorage) {
        lStorage.removeItem('isLoggedOut');
    }
}


function getLocalStorage() {

    var storage, fail, uid;
    try {
        uid = new Date;
        (storage = window.localStorage).setItem(uid, uid);
        fail = storage.getItem(uid) != uid;
        storage.removeItem(uid);
        fail && (storage = false);
    } catch (e) {}
    return storage
}
```

Now, HTML code to embed ,

```
<div id="LoggedoutMessage" style="display:none;position:absolute;background:black;height: 200%;width:100%;top: 0;z-index: 10000;opacity: 0.9;">
    <div id="login_box" style="position:fixed;left:38%;top:30%; padding:10px; width: 365px;margin: 0 auto;border: 0px solid #CCC;margin-top: 35px;height: 150px;background: white; border-radius:3px;">
        <div id="login_title">
            <h1>You have been logged out.</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="reLogin">
            <p>Please login to continue.</p>
            <g:link controller="dashBoard" action="index" target="_blank" onclick="logout();">Login</g:link>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Finally where you keep your html,keep this javascript code at top of it embedding script tag:

```
function poleSessionStatus() {

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: '',
        url: '<g:createLink action="ajaxCheckSession" controller="dashBoard"/>',
        success: function (data, textStatus) {
            //setTimeout ( "checkSession();", 5000);
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            $('#LoggedoutMessage').show();

        },
        complete: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus) {
            $.unblockUI();
        }
    });
}
```